# Move first file from folder to current directory

Tags: python-3.x

I need to move the first file of a folder to my current directory:

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.move(os.listdir('path to folder')[-1], os.getcwd())
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'name of  the file I want to move'
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when I've had to move files I wrote something like this:

```
for file in os.listdir(self.dlPth):    
    newfile = os.path.join(self.destPth, "name-of-new-file")
    shutil.move(os.path.join(self.dlPth,file), newfile)
```

destPth is the destination path and dlPth is the one where my file was downloaded.

Can you give the paths you are using? I mean the exact way you are writing them in your code?

---

**EDIT**

```
dl = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')
shutil.move(os.path.join(dl, os.listdir(dl)[0]), (dl+"\\test\\"))
```

listdir[index] will only return a file name, not a path. That's why it can't find the wanted file

Comment: :`shutil.move(os.listdir('E:/PyCharm/Translations/Testing/French_start')[-1], os.getcwd())`

Comment: Try writing it like `"E:\\PyCharm\\Translations..."`. And also, if you want the first file, why do you use [-1] instead of [0]? By calling [-1] you'll get the last entry of the list

Comment: I've tried that, the code finds the file name and return it in the error message. (The [1] was just a test with the last file, same result).

Comment: It is because you want to move a file that is not in your working directory. You have to use `os.path.join`to make a complete filename (E:\\PyCharm\\...). I edited my post so you can relate it to your question

Comment: `dl = os.path.join('E:\\PyCharm\\Translations\\Testing\\French_start')
go = os.path.join('E:\\PyCharm\\Translations\\Testing')
shutil.move(os.path.join(dl, os.listdir(dl)[0]), go)` It worked, thank you.